# TextEdit : Removing default text from untitled file

Tags: osx-mountain-lion, textedit

I tried to copy a very large text into an untitled TextEdit file. Now TextEdit starts showing progress wheel, whenever I try to edit or save the untitled file. I can get rid of the wheel only by force quitting the TextEdit app, but the problem is whenever I re-launch TextEdit, it again tries to show the large text which I pasted into before force quitting it.

Can anyone suggest me how can I remove the default text in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/48962 has the answer. Navigate to ~/Library/Containers/com.apple.TextEdit/Data/Library/Autosave Information/ and delete the relevant Unsaved Textedit Document file.

Comment: thnx a ton .. :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can disable restoring state by holding shift when opening an application. It works when the application is opened from Finder, Dock, or Launchpad, but not when it's opened from the Spotlight menu.

Comment: thnx for this useful info :-)